# Layer not shown in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In the current QGIS versions 2.18.6, 2.18.3 and 2.14 my top layer conating svg markers is not shown.  When trying the same on 2.99 nightly build, the layer is shown correctly. I find no issue / bug report about this, so I am turning to you pro's: Can you think of a reason for the layer not showing in the composer? In QGIS desktop it shows correctly, and no scale dependent visibility is used.